# Docker Selenium VPN: How to access internal or QA website on Docker container

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation, docker-selenium

I am trying to run selenium automation on QA/Staging server on Docker chrome container. I am using following code from  https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3.yml

to setup all containers.

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.1.3-20220405
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  edge:
    image: selenium/node-edge:4.1.3-20220405
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  firefox:
    image: selenium/node-firefox:4.1.3-20220405
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443

  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.1.3-20220405
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
```

code works fine on prod website but does not working on internal site (QA/Staging)
I am not sure how to run automation cases on  QA/stage

Can someone guide me what i can do to run test cases on internal(behind VPN).
VPN is currently connected

[image]